# prevent html5 invalid notification to pop up on input

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to set custom validity of html form element adding a handler function that sets custom validity, to element's "invalid" event. But since this event is fired every time user types something into input browser shows notitfication on every symbol typed. I wanna let user finish his typing attempt and show notification after the input loses focus. How can I do it with html5 validation?

Comment: use `onblur` attribute

Comment: If you use "pattern" attribute the notification pops up on every input event. How can I alter this behavior with JS? preventDefault() didn't help

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to go JS or a framework such as Angular where form validation is pretty straight forward. You can try to achieve this with CSS, and make validation more subtle, with maybe a green dot or a check mark or a red dot, or an x....etc, something like this:

```
Username: <input type="username" name="username" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" required>


input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
   background-image:url(images/green_dot.png)
   background-position: right top;
   border:none;
}
input:required:valid {
   background-image:url(images/red_dot.png)
   background-position: right top;
   border: none;
}
```

you can try and play around with CSS and that will get you a cleaner HTML form validation.
Hope it helps you in some way!

Comment: The point was to trigger validation notifications on change event but not on invalid event, which fires on every input event